# "earn" and its ambiguity direct object

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, complements

```
I earn my living by fighting on arena for many years as gladiator.
```

There is some ambiguity in this sentence. In my opinion it convey two different meanings:

```
1. I earn (money/and so on) for my living by fighting on arena for many years as gladiator.
2. I earn (freedom/my own life/prolongation of my life) by fighting on arena for many years as gladiator.
```

Are both of these meanings covered indeed?

And which of the following sentences are correct?

```
3. I earn my living for my own life by working freelance
4. I earn my living for my own living by working freelance
5. I earn my life by working freelance
6. I earn for my life by working freelance
```

Comment: In AmE *earn a living* refers ONLY to making money by providing your services.  It never refers to anything else, including *being alive.*  The concept of having to *earn your life* is difficult to comprehend.

Comment: It should be _in the arena_ instead of *_on arena_ (unless "arena" is a tv show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I earn (freedom/my own life/prolongation of my life) by fighting on arena for many years as gladiator.

Both meanings aren't really covered - *living* isn't the idiomatic word to express this.  More likely would be the phrase *the right to be a free man*, *the right to live*, or simply *my life*.

> And which of the following sentences are correct?

6 is the most correct.

3 - your living is automatically for your own life and that doesn't need to be expressed.

4 - your living can't be for itself so that just sounds weird

5 - this would be correct if you would die unless you are "working freelance"

Comment: Many thanks. The only last quetion, what about "I earn for my living by working freelance"? Does it sounds weird or similary "I earn my living by working freelance"?

Comment: The idiom is _earn your living_, meaning to earn enough money to support yourself. It doesn't mean _earn the right to life_. There are several mistakes in your sentence anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The noun 'living' in the context of earning, employment, etc, simply means 'the money that you earn from your job'. It does not have anything to do with 'living' meaning 'not being dead'.

> living
>
> noun
>
> the money that you earn from your job:
>
> What do you do for a living? (= What is your job?)
>
> I mean, I don't like my job but at least it's a living (= a way of
> earning money).

[Living (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/living)